# Compilation problem with Xelatex

Tags: xetex, citing, compiling

Last week-end, the compilation `biber` + `xelatex` worked very well.

But today I have moved my files in another place of my computer, and I can't compile any of my texts any more. Whenever I try, the citations remain `undefined`

I think the problem comes from my `.bib` file (because I haven't modified the former documents which used to work fine), but I can't find what it is.

I use this configuration :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, language=english]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\addbibresource{mabiblio.bib}
```

I and get this result :

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Dgscgc2013' on page 10 undefined on input line 125.
```

or this :

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 137.
```

and finally this :

```
 Latex failed to resolve 40 citation(s)
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 512
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Comment: Try to delete `*.bbl` and other files directly connected to `bibtex`, but not `.bib` file, also delete the `.aux` file and recompile

Comment: I don't have a `*.bbl` file when I compile, it might be the problem ?

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` at all?

Comment: Do you have a .blg-file? What does it say?

Comment: No I don't have a `.blg-file`. And the terminal says :   `Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:"The State can’t do everything any more” : Understand
ing the evolution of civil defense policies in France" and rerun LaTeX afterwards.`

Comment: It says also this : `Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend. To use BibTeX, load biblatex with the "backend=bibtex" option.`

Comment: Well and did you try to run biber? (with xelatex and unicode you should really use biber instead of bibtex).

Comment: Actually I use `latexmkrc` wich automatically compile for me so I'm not sure exactly what I use...

Comment: a complete minimal example could help, too: including at least the citation that's causing the problem.  it would be good, also, to see the stuff in the `.bib` file that you want to refer to.

Comment: Ok, I have followed your last advice, and did a new document and it works (the `.bbl` appears, etc.). But I could not say what is the difference between the two of them : they are in the same file, they use the same `.bib` file. But only in one of them the `.bbl` appears and the bibliography works. I am pretty sure that it is a very common mistake, but I could say what.

Comment: Run biber once on the command line to find out if it works.

Comment: Okay now I have tried on different texts : some of them run biber and generate a `.bbl`, and some others don't. I can't figure why.

Comment: Check again if you really don't have blg-file (if you have windows: windows can hide the extension and fool you by showing some other data type). Check also the log-files.

Comment: No I use Ubuntu. I just took the time to copy-paste all my document and re-put the code in order. Everything works now, but I still don't really get it why it wasn't working